# Does nix provide package options / parameters? How do I list them?

Tags: nix

For example I can query for available package versions of llvm:

```
$ nix-env -qa llvm
...
llvm-4.0.1
llvm-5.0.2
llvm-6.0.1
```

With homebrew I can provider an option when installing a package like llvm, in this case the `--shared` option:

```
$ brew install llvm --shared
```

Does nix support providing package specific options like this? Is there a way to list the available options of a package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, nix derivations can come with optional arguments. For example, the derivation for LLVM 6 [nixpkgs/development/compilers/llvm/6/llvm.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/compilers/llvm/6/llvm.nix) starts like this:

```
{ stdenv
, fetch
...
, zlib
, debugVersion ? false
, enableManpages ? false
, enableSharedLibraries ? true
, enableWasm ? true
, darwin
}:
```

You can supply values for these arguments on the `nix-env` command line using the options `--arg` or `--argstr`, compare the [man page](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-env). E.g.,

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.llvm --arg enableSharedLibraries false
```

I'm not aware of an easier way to find out such options than to read the nixpkgs source, unfortunately.

Comment: The difference between `--arg` and `--argstr` is that `--arg`'s second argument is literally parsed to a nix value, whereas `--argstr`'s second argument is automatically made into string. To pass a string to `--arg` would require adding quotes to it, e.g., `--arg parameter \"value\"`

Comment: Anyone know how to pass arg when a pkg is used in the `buildInputs`?